# Visual Studio 2008 messed up font

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I just finished installing a large Windows update on one of our desktops, after which the font in Visual Studio 2008 C++ IDE seems to be somewhat messed up. Take a look:

[image]

And here's from a different machine:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

PS. Note that this earlier version of VS did not have a zoom function, so doing Ctrl+ or Ctrl- doesn't do anything.

Comment: Same question as [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286196/is-it-just-my-imagination-or-have-the-fonts-gotten-even-uglier).

Comment: @HansPassant: Oh wow. Thanks. Removed `KB3013455`, wasted half-an-hour, and it worked! So no more updates in my immediate future: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/566588/did-new-windows-updates-and-now-my-fonts-look-bad/?p=3624919

Comment: Hmm, maybe you ought to be a bit more concerned about having wonky fonts on your machine.  But yes, it is easier to flip the ignore bit.

Comment: @HansPassant: Hmm. Let's see which one I would choose? A zero-day font vulnerability that may or may not infect my computer if I go to some unknown site, or inability to read my screen in **most** of the applications (including web browser) that was caused by an update/MS-mal-ware.... hmm... "tough choice".